# How illegal is it to use inline CSS in a site?

Tags: html, css, conventions

```
<h1 style="margin: -20px 0 40px 0">Heading</h1>
```

**vs**

```
.intro h1 { margin: -20px 0 40px 0; }
```

---

Here's my dilema, I have a page that uses a unique styling from the rest of the pages for a single heading. It's hard for me to decide if I have to declare those properties in my external stylesheet or just hardcode it directly to that element.

The property that I would have to changes is only margin. It will just correct a spacing problem.

**I see pros and cons in using the either:**

If I declare it in the external stylesheet, this will probably be a conventional way of manipulating the look of the element but for a single element, I find it too much.

If I declare it inline to the element, it's convenient to update later on rather than going through a bunch of css rules just to find that specific rule declaration.

I need someone to back me up rather than deciding by my instinct. If I would have to choose an approach, I would use inline.

Comment: Use an inline style and make sure the CSS police can't trace it back to you.

Comment: why do you find it "too much" ? I.e, you could have an element with an id `#myelement` and use it into the stylesheet. That would mean the `#` selector should not be used at all ?

Comment: Have your fun now, pay the maintenance later. If you know what you are doing there is no problem, but know that it will be a hassle in the long run. Maybe there is no long run in this case, so who cares?

Comment: .css file, not inline. Even if you use it only once, give it a "smart class name" so that you can re-use it. The time will come where you need it once again.

Comment: I once gut busted by the police when I was inlining around a block-element. They wanted to see my ID. I said: 'I'm sorry. I have none. I'm a classy person'. Was pretty bad.

Answer (score 3):

From the awesome peeps at Google:

> **Requirements**
>
> There is a tradeoff here between requests and cacheability: including
>   the CSS directly in the HTML avoids making an additional request to
>   the external CSS resource, but if the CSS file is large (and doesn't
>   change often), it may be better to keep it separate from the HTML so
>   that it can be cached by the browser. Thus, the Inline CSS filter will
>   only inline CSS files below a certain size threshold, which can be
>   adjusted using the CssInlineMaxBytes directive.
>
> It is possible for CSS files to contain small snippets of JavaScript
>   code, at least for certain browsers. To avoid opening up cross-domain
>   scripting vulnerabilities, the Inline CSS filter will only inline an
>   external CSS file if it is being served from the same domain as the
>   HTML file into which it is to be inlined.
>
> **Risks**
>
> The 'Inline CSS' filter is low to moderate risk. It should be safe for
>   most pages, but it could potentially break scripts that walk the DOM
>   looking for and examining  or  tags.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-inline

Answer (score 1):

For me it all comes down to how much time you want to spend maintaing your design.  Consider these three examples:

Inline (tag):

```
<h1 style="margin: -20px 0 40px 0">Heading</h1>
```

Inline (document):

```
<style>
  .intro h1 { margin: -20px 0 40px 0; }
</style>
<h1 class="intro">Heading</h1>
```

And separated:

page.css:

```
.intro h1 { margin: -20px 0 40px 0; }
```

page.html:

```
<h1 class="intro">Heading</h1>
```

All three will product the same result, however in the first two examples, if the style of an intro header changes then it has to be updated everywhere this code has been copied.  With the inline (tag) version you may not even know if you missed one because there is no semantic pattern to search against.  The third version is in my opinion the best approach.  Your HTML is filled with markup and semantic meaning while your design in centrally managed.

Answer (score 0):

You declare specific element rules all the time by using `#id` in CSS.

Everything layout related should be found in the CSS, this makes the confusion easier when you're trying to fix the margin at a later time.
When you use the debugger in your browser it will be very easy to find the line it's defined on anyway, (or atleast see the rule that applies the styling if it's minimized) so saying "it will be easier to update later" kinda falls to the ground (if you ask me)

The only valid reason I see for inline CSS is for when you use javascript to control the styling dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I would declare it in an external stylesheet if you're already using one. It's nice having all of the CSS styling code in a single (sometimes a few) stylesheet file(s). Even if it's only used once on a single page. This way if you ever need to change it again - you won't have to hunt down that file or sort through the code to find it.

Alternatively, you could declare the element rules in the  of the file. This will apply the styling ONLY to this page and can easily be located at the beginning of the file.

I'm no certified professional.. but I've taken several web design and web programming classes and have played around with the aspects of making websites look nice. I've always been told that proper web design technique shouldn't use inline styling and to only declare styling rules in the  of the HTML file if you're wanting a few specific rules for a single page.

It's wise to keep the styling together and organized so you can change it easily at any time. Adding styles inline can cause others to overlook tags that they would expect to simply be something like  rather than looking for a tag that contains much more within it. This also keeps the code nice and clean. Keep it minimal, simple, and easy on the eyes.

Good luck!